# Don't hide (un)deletion votes cast on deleted posts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, 10k-tools

I'm a big fan of the votes tab in the profile page, as it allows me to keep track of my usage of the moderation tools. Or at least it would, if votes cast on deleted posts didn't unceremoniously disappear.

Although I don't like it, I can live with that for (up|down|close|reopen)-votes. In fact, I didn't even notice it before gaining 10k rep on SU. But it renders the **deletion** and **undelete** subtabs pretty much useless, since it hides – by design – *all* successful deletion and (yet) unsuccessful undeletion votes.

@slhck suggested in an answer to [this related question](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5221) the following rationale for this behavior:

> While this sounds strange, it's just a result of the … let's call it "Stack Exchange policy" of not showing lists of deleted posts to non-moderators. In my opinion this policy is a little incoherent, because your flagging record shows deleted posts [...]

Actually, the flagging record shows deleted posts to pretty much *all* users. So does the reputation tab of the user profile (as long as you earned/lost reputation on that post).

If that is in fact the reason, why can't a 10k user see a list of posts he voted on (and thus, already saw)?

Comment: [TL;DR](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrQO0.jpg)

Comment: TL;DR: Don't hide deleted posts in the votes sections relating to deletions? (Sorry, just making sure I actually understand what you mean `:)`)

Comment: @minitech: Precisely.

Comment: Trivia: we actually had this on the list to implement at one time, and somehow it morphed into [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile) instead. I blame high levels of gamma radiation.

Comment: Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1696/cant-see-undelete-votes-for-deleted-posts

Comment: I'm working on this now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for this suggestion! I've modified the code so that 10K users can see votes on (un)deleted posts under the appropriate tabs (deletion, undelete) of the votes section of their profile. This will be live in the next prod build (> rev `2014.7.3.2354`). Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: 5 days without a build, any ETA?

Comment: Great question. The 4th of July long weekend of course brought work functions mostly to a halt. :) We typically build 1-10x per day, so I'd fairly safely say that you'll see it sometime in the next 24 hours.

Answer (score 6):

This.

I'm pretty sure I voted to undelete a question a couple of days ago (and another one today).  Apparently, neither of them have been undeleted yet, since the last undelete vote shown in my profile is from March last year.  I'd kind of like to go back and see if anyone else has agreed with my vote, **but I can't, since there's no link to the post in my profile!**

If I'd flagged the post for ♦ mod attention instead, I could've found the link to the post in my flag history.  If it was my own post, I could've found it under [deleted recent questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile).  But since I just voted to undelete it, there doesn't seem to be any way for me to find it again.

I'd *very* much like to see this information shown, at least when viewing your *own* profile.