# How can I see the question which I've downvoted

Tags: support, down-votes

So, as said in the title - how can I see the question which I've downvoted?
The reason for my question is that in my users summary tab I see this:

> [image: total votes]

But when I click on the `votes`->`downvote` in my users profile I get this message:

> You have no votes.

Comment: Wow what an extreme vote ratio.

Comment: @Nikola Just in case : if you downvote a question, [you won't lose rep](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down).

Comment: @dystroy: it says in the link `Downvotes on answers remove 1 reputation from you, the voter.`

Comment: @Nikola But it also says "Downvotes on questions are free". I'm not saying you must downvote questions but it's a little strange you saw 123 questions needing upvote and none asking for a downvote.

Comment: @dystroy: ah, right, I missed that part :), so only on answers.

Comment: new tag needed `[specific-downvote]` :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **Votes Cast** statistic takes votes on deleted posts into account ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117846/votes-cast-should-include-votes-on-deleted-contributions)), but you can only see those posts in the **votes** tab that haven't been deleted.

Even for 10k users (which can see deleted posts), it's impossible to see which deleted posts they downvoted, voted to close or even [voted to delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140328/dont-hide-undeletion-votes-cast-on-deleted-posts).