# What is the 'deleted recent questions' page in the user profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, deleted-posts-pages

On the bottom of questions tab of the user profile, there is a link that states "Deleted recent questions".

[image]

This links to `http://site.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/xxxxx`.  The title of the page is 'User Flair', which seems odd in itself.

What is this page meant to show?  Whenever I have looked at it it is blank for me, to test I deleted [one of my questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22844/how-can-i-assign-a-picture-for-a-name-only-text-sender) on Android.SE however *six hours later* the recently deleted questions page was still blank.

Is this feature not working, am I incorrectly interpreting it (for example is it only moderator/community deleted questions) or was my experiment a failure due to long term caching? Having now re-read the link I see that whilst the title is "Recently deleted questions", the link is to "deleted recent questions" - does the question have to have been recently *asked*?

Comment: Recently the functionality has been changed in such way that you can find here list of all your deleted questions (not only the recent ones).
It was announced here: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645#374184) (The linked feature request is now marked status-completed.)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's an experiment.

See, [this is one of the all-time most popular feature-requests here on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted). But past experience suggests that implementing it *as-requested* would result in unbearable amounts of wailing, gnashing of teeth, meta complaints, Twitter rants, cats sleeping with dogs, CHAOS...

So instead, we're showing a link (visible only to profile owners and moderators) on the Questions and Answers tabs that'll list the given user's deleted questions or answers, currently limited to those <s>posted</s> deleted in the past 60 days (**editor's note:** this was [changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343215/377214) in February 2020).

So far, this has proved to be unobtrusive enough to avoid serious problems. We'll continue to monitor its use, and any questions or complaints that result from it.

Comment: The page title is "User Flair", I sure hope you plan to change that if the experiment goes well and it's kicked out to the open.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That was definitely just an oversight. :) It should be fixed soon (in the next build, I believe).

Comment: Cheers @Laura! While at it, can the link please be changed from "deleted recent questions" to "recently deleted questions"?

Comment: The current wording is more descriptive of what it actually *does*, @Sha

Comment: Is this now live for everyone? If not, how do you determine the select few people who get to see it? Is it based on reputation?

Comment: It's live for everyone, @Cody.

Comment: In my "deleted recent answers", some items are not clickable even though I have over 10K so can view my answers even on deleted questions. So why unclickable?

Comment: Please report that as a bug, @Sha. Also report the bit where even the clickable ones don't actually link to the *answer*. Thanks!

Comment: @Shog9 cheers, wasn't sure it's a bug at first. Reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193203/152859) and [separate report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193195/152859) about the "clickable ones don't actually link to the answer", which I missed. :)

Comment: Looks like this feature doesn't exist anymore. I deleted my only question on Arqade just yesterday and I have no way to find it again. It wasn't well received and I'm not heartbroken about it. However, I was contemplating reasking it on a different site at a later date.

Comment: Still there, @Ellesedil. [Here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/68492)

Comment: Oh, neat. Did the actual link under the questions/answers tab get removed? I have no such link on my profile (0 Questions You have not asked any questions), nor can I find one elsewhere, which prompted my comment.

Comment: You should still see it, @Ellesedil. If you don't, then post a bug report on http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com with a screenshot of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=questions

Comment: I proposed any deleted post can be accessible by the owner forever. That can keep the owner aware of what questions he has had, the comments and answers that he had received,  which are still useful when he encounters the same problem again in the future. Last but not least, he can also learn from why they were deleted. Shall I post this proposal as a new post?

Comment: @Tim: Yes! Please make that a proposal. My most popular question [is headed for the bit-bucket](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3306/senior-moderator-intervention-requested/) because a group of moderators thinks info on old software is useless.

Comment: @Shog9, Btw regarding *"past experience suggests that implementing it as-requested would result in unbearable amounts of wailing"*, has it ever been implemented as requested before?

Comment: After two years, is this still just an experiment? Are there any changes planned for it?

Comment: Is this still the current state? It would be better if it wasn't, given [this Programmers meta question where the asker can't see why he was question blocked](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/8020/4).

Comment: He's question-blocked because he asked a bunch of questions that were heavily downvoted and then closed, @thomas. The system warned him about this repeatedly while these questions were still accessible. If you want to help him *now*, some concrete advice on how to salvage those questions is essential; unless you see yourself reopening them, there's no real point in dredging them up.

Comment: This 60-day limit is very annoying. I wish we could see all deleted questions.

Comment: Shog, can you please take a look at the [issue reported here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8623/31260)? User says they were unable to find their first deleted question in recent deleted questions until they posted yet another question. Some suspect caching but it's kind of hard to believe as it seemed unavailable for asker for about an hour or two (not to mention how harmful it would be if caching like that would block them from learning in 40 minutes period of throttling for new users)

Comment: I've suspected a bug there for a long time... Will test when able. Thanks @gnat

Comment: thanks! Would be great if you also test whether system shows warning when user attempts to post next question because [according to them](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8623/the-very-first-question-if-deleted-cannot-be-retrieved-until-2nd-question-is-add#comment27035_8623 "'I didn't notice any warning or unusual message while adding 2nd question'") it wasn't shown. Though maybe -2 at the first question weren't enough to trigger it

Answer (score 1):

Can the link be hidden if there are no recently deleted questions? Otherwise it just takes up space on the page and makes the user think one of their questions or answers was deleted. On SO, one of my questions was deleted for inactivity because the answer was put in the comments, and when I tried to find it, this link was no help because it was not "recent" enough. If the link is going to appear when there are no recently deleted items, then I think questions/answers deleted from all time should appear.

Why go to this link

[image: my questions]

just to see this?

[image: no deleted recent questions]

I also agree that users should be notified when their question is closed or deleted, but I guess that's a feature for another thread.