# Why do I have an Answer Ban already?

Tags: support, post-ban

I very new to StackExchange and I have already have an Answer Ban, but I only have one question (which has no down votes) and I have zero answers. I don't even know who to ask on what to do to fix this. I've read the Help Center message, but it doesn't make any sense and seems like a catch 22. I rarely will have questions to ask, but I wanted to start answering some questions. As it is right now, I can't answer, vote or anything, but ask questions, is that right?

Comment: Are you on a shared internet connection?

Comment: You can't get an answer ban without having answered something so this must be an ip address thing (however, note deleted answers count too)

Comment: No. I am on my home internet connection (Verizon FiOS.) So, if it's an IP address ban, how is that right (to ban Dynamic IP addresses?) What can I do about it?

Comment: try an ip release/renew and see if that helps (basically, try to get a new ip address assigned)

Comment: No way to do that (probably wouldn't change anyway) from this router, and a restart won't change it (had the same IP until I got a new router recently for almost a year.)

Comment: Try calling your IP company. If they can't do anything, you can always switch to Tor.

Comment: You have three deleted answers from May 2012: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954764/imagick-php-5-4-extension-does-not-work-with-relative-paths-windows/10462945#10462945, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528743/uploading-without-corrupting-files/10666401#10666401, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901830/jpeg-files-uploaded-to-a-php-script-arrive-corrupt-but-not-all-the-time/10660454#10660454. All non-answers deleted by moderators.

Comment: ..and yet I keep hoping that the information provided is really all there is...

Comment: Forgot all about those. I wrote those before I realized the format of the site was that they had to be actual answers, and not discussion. I admit, that was my mistake. In fact, I did not realize that until I heard Joel and crew talk about that on their Podcast. How do I get myself out of this hole now? It seems the only solution is ask questions? Is that right? What if I have no questions to ask? Do I just make stuff up? I'm a seasoned PHP programmer and want to get more involved.

Comment: See the link in the comment above (or the duplicate link once this question gets closed).

Comment: @KeithDavis: Well, as the FAQ recommends, contribute in other ways. (Only developers know the specifics!)

Comment: @minitechη What other ways? I can't vote, I can't comment, I can't answer. What other ways are there?

Comment: @KeithDavis minitech gave you the links to the posts.  My recommendation is to edit the posts and attempt to answer the questions legitimately (with an answer that does not duplicate existing answers) and undeleted them.

Comment: @KeithDavis: Asking good questions and suggesting edits are some.

Comment: It always ends up being deleted answers. If you can improve those deleted answers to make them real answers (and then get a mod to undelete them) thats the easiest way out

Comment: @KeithDavis the post ban does not impact your ability to vote or comment.  Your inability to do both is only based on your rep.  Once you earn enough rep through asking or editing, you will be able to vote and comment.

Comment: @KeithDavis Or email the developer team. They're very helpful.

Comment: What if I don't know the answers? Again, I admit, I misunderstood how the site was to be used, but I understand now.

Comment: "To fix answer ban, ask good questions, fix your deleted posts (that aren't answers at all)"... Makes no sense to me. I can sympathize with this guy.

Comment: @KeithDavis it is not going to be a fast process.  Best advice I can offer is research the question and see if you can learn the answer.  And you don't necessarily have to fix all 3 posts.  1 or 2 might be enough to lift the ban.  Then if you give enough good answers after the ban is lifted, the ones you didn't fix won't be a problem.

Comment: @KeithDavis Then spend some time contributing in ways still possible to you to see your ban lifted. That's really all you can do. It will take time, but if you're serious about contributing, then that's all you can do.

Comment: @Bart Such as? What, suggesting edits? Asking questions *just for the sake of lifting the answer ban*?

Comment: @WesleyMurch I don't know the exact details of the algorithm involved, but yes, anything that can get you some reputation. Asking decent questions, editing content into shape....

Comment: @WesleyMurch I can sympathize too. If someone takes this as a discussion site and attempts discussion of topics they don't understand (e.g. what if they're the user who says "Thanks everybody who answered here! I'm wondering about this related thing, what do I do?") the repairing their answers thing isn't a recourse.

Comment: But my rep is so low, I can't vote or comment.

Comment: @KeithDavis I think they want you do do janitor work as a punishment. Try this as an experiment. Suggest several edits (substantial improvements) to existing posts, see where that gets you. Make sure they are good and get accepted.

Comment: The regularity with which this happens really would support showing users their deleted content

Comment: @RichardTingle A lot of people [agree with you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted). Unfortunately the only person whose opinion mattered at that time didn't like the idea (see the heavily downvoted answer).

Comment: If those three 14 months old deleted posts were really "forum-style posts" rather than Q&A style answers (and also to posts that have an accepted answer, so what's to fix on those deleted posts), then all this feels a bit harsh to me. Note the *"If you really, really think the ban is an error"* part in the duplicate (in the part about the *question* ban) then, Keith.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Do note that they are slowly [coming around to that idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-recently-deleted-questions-page-in-the-user-profile).

Comment: @pubsee2003 As far as correcting my answers, what if the question has now already been answered with the correct answer? 2 of them have the correct answer and the 3rd is actually a duplicate of one of other ones.

Comment: @KeithDavis the one post that was self answered due to the bug is unanswerable, but with enough research, I think the other 2 might have a unique solution.  Just because a post has an accepted answer doesn't mean you shouldn't try to answer.  You don't need an accept answer, you just need a valid answer so you can safely ask it be undeleted.  And it doesn't have to be completely unique, but if you can add new info that is not present in the other answers, that is usually enough.  The "unique" solution for the 2nd bug post might just be another workaround.

Comment: @KeithDavis I'm not advocating this for most cases, but in your situation, the idea is not to make it a good answer but make it a valid answer that won't get downvoted so it can be undeleted.  I don't have the rep to see the deleted posts, but unless they have a lot of downvotes, my guess is the ban might be lifted if you can get one undeleted.

Comment: Well, I really feel pretty defeated at this point. I'm ok with all of the rules, but not having any kind of "hey, I was new, I screwed up, mechanism" has probably turned me off for good. I just don't have time to jump through all of these hoops. It was an honest mistake and I’ve spent almost an hour just today trying to fix it and I feel like the solutions are a hack and not worth my effort at this point (especially since it’s a gamble that I will even get un-banned for doing what I’m told.) Maybe one day my opinion will change (or the rules), but for now, I’m done. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @KeithDavis I actually sympathize because the answer ban is extremely tough to lift in these circumstances, which is why I've been trying to offer some suggestions.  But for everyone who made an honest mistake (like you), there are 10 who just don't care.  The post-ban is designed in such a way that it can't be lifted by anyone and puts the burden on the poster to fix it themselves.  In that way, it is a very fair process as it doesn't allow anyone to play favorites.  I wish I could help more.

Comment: @KiethDavis Note that asking questions you know the answer to is perfectly acceptable. In most cases you would also post the answer to the question, but obviously that wouldn't work in your case. If you have an interesting question to ask that is not a duplicate that you think would help others, go ahead and post it. That should be a fairly easy way to get your rep up for other privileges to combat the ban. Since you're trying to do this in good faith and presumably would ask quality questions, it wouldn't be very hard either (I don't think.) Good luck, I hope this helps you!

Answer (score -2):

This is most likely a shared IP thing. Are you sure you don't have any deleted answers? Well, how bans work is that we don't just ban the user, we ban the IP address. The only thing you can do is get a new IP address or use something like Tor.

Normally, a router reboot should give you a new IP address, but in your case, it sounds like that doesn't work. Could it be that your router is configured with a static IP address? If it isn't, try it. If that doesn't work, the only thing I can recommend is that you call your ISP and request a new IP address.

If a new IP address doesn't fix the issue, it sounds highly likely that you have deleted answers.

Comment: Looks like OP "forgot" about some removed answers.

Comment: Nah, this is most likely a "I gave answers that weren't really answers" thing.

Comment: Assuming all the information given in the question was correct (which it turns out isnt correct) then this would have been the correct answer. Its a +1 from me

Comment: "Assuming all the information given in the question was correct (which it turns out isnt correct) " What information was not correct?

Comment: Never mind, because I had deleted non-answers.