# "Deleted Recent Answers" showing unclickable items when the parent question is deleted

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, deleted-posts-pages

The recent "Deleted Recent Answers" page is a welcome feature. However, I noticed that even though I can see deleted questions, answers I posted on questions that were deleted are not clickable.

<strike>Can this be changed please? I can still find those questions, Google Cache or old inbox items, it would be much more convenient to have the link in the same place though.</strike>

Another option is to not show those answers at all in the first place, as they were deleted only as a side effect, not directly.

Per [Shog9 comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-recently-deleted-questions-page-in-the-user-profile/185492?noredirect=1#comment604852_185492), this is a bug - please fix it. This likely has to behave like reputation history when "show removed posts" is ticked.

Comment: You copied my draft question. :(

Comment: @hims056 Mind Reading spell, piece of cake! :P

Comment: Should these links be clickable only to users with >10k reputation (i.e. those who can already see deleted questions)? Or do you want to create a loophole that allows <10ks to view deleted questions if they had an answer posted?

Comment: @Cody no no, only for >10K. Don't want to mess things up. It's already working this way in reputation tab as far as I remember. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first pass at this code had a bug where it didn't consider privileges when determining if you could see a deleted post or not, it only looked at ownership rules (ie. everyone was treated as if they had 1 rep).

This was fixed in the latest deploy.  All your answers should be clickable if you're a mod or if you have [access to moderation tools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).