# Closed, deleted, rewarded: what's going on?

Tags: support, reputation, specific-question

I do not understand what's going on with (the community-wiki) [What is the best macro-benchmarking tool / framework to measure a single-threaded complex algorithm in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7146207/750378):

- the subject ends with "[closed]"
- below the question, it says closed as off-topic
- then it says deleted
- the question/answer is no longer listed on my question list
- but I got rewarded 50 points in my popup-overview when I hover over my name
- I do not see the +50 when I look at my reputation.

So what's going on here? The whole thread really got deleted? But I got rewarded for it?

Comment: By norms, you shouldn't have been rewarded anything. Both the question and your answer are Community Wiki.

Comment: You mean "shouldn't have been rewarded"? By norms? You mean it's a bug?

Comment: Did you spend a bounty on that question in the past?

Comment: Might be. You should add a screenshot of the popup-box showing the change. What do you notice on [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) wrt question no. 7146207

Comment: Given some of the previous bounties by the OP, that doesn't seem unlikely indeed @juergend.

Comment: @hjpotter92: Only the following: -- 2011-08-21 rep 0     = 43        
 2   7146207 (5)
 2   7146207 (5)
 2   7146207 (5)
-- 2011-08-24 rep 0     = 78        
 2   7146207 (5)
-- 2011-08-28 rep +10   = 110       
 2   7217950 (10)
 2   7146207 (5)
 2   7146207 (5)
 2   7146207 (5)
 1   7212712 (2)

Comment: Thanks all. It is the bounty of +50 I rewarded. It is also no longer listed on my bounty list. Now I understand.

Comment: It is a request for a tool recommendation. So it is closed for that reason. This question came along in the delete vote queue so I voted to delete because my reasoning is it will attract similar questions. As for salvage of the question: You could tell which tool you used to measure X but the outcome is not what you want or not suitable for your setting, or that you used a tool to measure Y but you're as well interested in measuring X. The answer either solve your issue with the current tool or you get other tools recommended.

Comment: @rene: thanks for the comment: I just moved that part of my question to a new thread: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203403/saving-the-contents-of-a-deleted-thread-undelete-publish-elsewhere-without-co

Comment: @DaveBallakauser750378 there is no such thing as a 'thread' on Stackoverflow. There are just questions and answers. Discussions are discouraged.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. The question was closed about a month ago.
2. It was closed as off topic since it falls under "recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource" which are no longer on topic in Stack Overflow.
3. It was deleted yesterday after getting five delete votes from 10K+ users.
4. True, while one can see his/her own deleted question having a direct link, it's not listed the question list in his/her profile.
5. The +50 rep is because of an old bounty you placed over two years ago, bounty points are revoked when the question is deleted.
6. You don't see the +50 in the reputation history because the question is deleted, try ticking the "show removed posts" checkbox and you should see it.

Also worth to mention you keep the reputation earned before the question was turned to CW, since it has score of more than 3 and was visible on the site for more than 30 days. ([Source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/) - search for "if you’ve contributed something worthwhile to the site, you should keep the reputation")

Comment: (As for 4., see [What is the 'Recently Deleted Questions' page in the user profile?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-recently-deleted-questions-page-in-the-user-profile) But you might be right, as that is *"currently limited to those posted in the past 60 days"*.)