# Saving the contents of a deleted thread: undelete? Publish elsewhere (without copyright problems)?

Tags: discussion, support, copyright

The (community-wiki) [What is the best macro-benchmarking tool / framework to measure a single-threaded complex algorithm in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7146207/750378) just got deleted. Since I put in a lot of effort and obviously many users find it useful, I do not want the contents to vanish.

What can I do to make it be undeleted/reopened? The suggestion is to "describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it" instead of asking for a suggested tool. Since I am not asking for an opinion but do state my problem and requirements for the tool, would it be sufficient to rephrase my two questions at the end?

If there is no chance of getting it undeleted again, may I use the vanished contents and publish it on my blog? What's the copyright of it after being deleted? (It was community wiki, but as you can see, I contributed 99%.)

Comment: Reopened is unlikely, since it's by definition off-topic now. Undeleted, perhaps. But you could grab the content and publish it somewhere with the proper attribution. Google will still have a cache of it.

Comment: Why not do what a user did for the Free programming Ebooks post and put it on Github?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That post doesn't seem popular enough for a historical lock, so reposting the content on your own blog or web site is probably the best course of action here.  You might want to mention that you originally posted it to Stack Overflow and that it was closed as off-topic for being a tool recommendation question, but since the terms of the license on Stack Exchange say that you're licensing the content to the community to reuse, you're not really restricted from using your own original content at all.

Comment: Is there an actual rule when a question counts as popular enough? With 10k views for instance?

Comment: @juergend There's no rule that I'm aware of, but most of the questions with historical locks have several tens of thousands of views.

Comment: Does it seem useful enough (even if not excessively popular) to **not** simply throw it away? Sure someone can copy it onto another site, but why not just have SO hold onto it? I thought we had more of a tendency to keep old useful questions rather than deleting by default and only keeping by exception.

Comment: @Dukeling It's not really up to me. People can still vote to undelete if they think the question should stay on SO.

Comment: The question got undeleted, thanks everyone :) I did rephrase the questions at the end to no longer provoke discussions/opinions...

Answer (score 3):

Exactly for this case we have [*historical locks*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for).

> A historical lock preserves older content that was **very popular** when it was originally posted, but is **now off-topic** or otherwise out of scope for the site it is posted on.

Comment: Any insight into how it got deleted and how popular it was?

Comment: Oh, I did not know that :) Will it show up in the search result just like undeleted posts? But you will not be able to update the long list, right? Can I instead just use my own answer in my blog (and add as a footnote that it originates from stackoverflow but got deleted there)?

Comment: @Bart: Well, the question got 30 net upvotes, 17 favorites, and the answer got 24 upvotes. Can I somehow still find out how many views it got?

Comment: Viewed 3882 times

Comment: @Fluffeh: thanks. That's not very much, is it?

Comment: Not all that much indeed @DaveBallakauser750378. And I think links to the content are also taken into account. Without a lot of views, and with not much chance of breaking other content, a historical lock is not all that likely.