# Why only "deleted recent answers"?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I found this button at bottom of my answers : `deleted recent answers`.

Why limit only to recent answers?

I remember that last year I posted an answer that got five -1 votes. I deleted it, but regretted after, since I learned something really great from the comments.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile

Comment: @Oded Ok, so it is an experiment? 60 days now, and maybe all available Q&A later?

Comment: Maybe. Big maybe.

Comment: The biggest question is - why to show deleted content at all? After all, it's deleted ;)

Comment: Shog9 put it nicely and I tend to agree with him: *(showing all deleted posts) would result in unbearable amounts of wailing, gnashing of teeth, meta complaints, Twitter rants, cats sleeping with dogs, CHAOS*

Comment: @Mołot That is discussed in linked questions. There are some really interesting questions, that got 100s vote-ups, which got deleted (see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73455/popular-deleted-so-su-programmers-questions-list)). Me personally would like to find some of my answers that I deleted them.