# Listing MY questions asked, that were deleted (by me or others), within my profile page

Tags: feature-request

Today, I came into meta so that I could ***re-list*** (or make viewable again) a question that I had asked last week, as I have found more information on the topic, and feel the question with more information could be relevant again.

Now I can't find the original question and would have loved to have started with the original text from that question, simply add and re-submit / list.

Would it be possible to keep a running history of asked questions that have been closed by others, or even by ourselves within our profiles, so that we could return to them later?  Shouldn't this be part of your "Activity" anyway?

Comment: There already is such a list; go to your Questions tab and click the 'deleted recent questions' link at the bottom.

Comment: Anyone can see their (or anyone else's) closed questions on their profile.  Deleted questions are different.

Comment: And I think you meant *that have been **deleted** by others,*. Closed questions are still listed in the usual places.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - good point, yes as the title says.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted Though I'm loathe to close it because maybe there's new information (and new data) that we can show to support this feature request.  Also, it's a *little* different because the user talks about 're-listing' their question, and that's a different subject space.

Answer (score 5):

We don't want you to "re-list" questions (to mean we don't want you to repost your question). We want you to improve your existing question.  That's why there's an "Edit" link on every question, so that it can be improved.

If your question was deleted, that means it has serious issues. If you simply re-ask the same question, it's going to get deleted again, and you're probably going to make the community (and moderators) cranky because you decided to repost something that had already been deleted once.

There is [a long standing feature request to allow people to see their own deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted), and there is a poorly-implemented form of this feature request [in allowing you to see recent deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile/185492#185492).

In the meantime, If you need your question undeleted or a link to it, flag one of your posts and tell us the title (or something) so we know which deleted question you're referring to, and we'll send you a link so you can edit it and flag it for undeletion.

***Update***:

Your only deleted question on Stack Overflow is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268268/if-variable-constant-or-if-constant-variable-that-is-the-topic), and you deleted it because it was on the verge of being closed by the community as primarily opinion based.

This question (and the questions like it) are not welcome on Stack Overflow. Any time you're asking for 'community preference' (or the oft-used and often misunderstood 'best practices') you can be sure the question is borderline *in the best of circumstances*.  [Unless you have an awesome question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595964/is-there-a-use-case-for-singletons-with-database-access-in-php/4596323#4596323), it's going to be closed and downvoted.