# Make "deleted recent questions" clearer

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions

Currently, if you're a new user and you ask a queston that gets deleted, later when you come back and wonder where the question went, you *do* have a way of seeing it, but it's not very clear, particularly not to people for whom English is a second, third, or fourth language:

[image]

That's [this experiment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/134069), which has been continued since.

Here's that in the context context of the full page:

[image]

As the list includes recent questions that were deleted (as opposed to *recently-deleted* questions, which would be slightly different; it goes by creation date, not deletion date), I suggest updating it to say one of the following (in preference order):

1. **View your recent deleted questions (1)**
2. **View your deleted recent questions (1)**
3. **View your recent questions that have been deleted (1)**

...where the number is the number of questions you'll see if you click it.