# Where is my question? (After marked as too broad)

Tags: support, deleted-questions

In 13th of December 2016 I signed up for Cognitive Sciences Beta and asked a question about empathy of humans for animals and the reasons for it. The question was quite broad and marked as such. I got good feedback how to rework my question to be able to be answered. Now I find the time to rework my question but can't find the question in my profile anymore.

So where has my question gone to?

Comment: Are questions on stackexchange deleted automatically if they are flagged? Is the author informed of this deletion? Does the author before deletion gets an email with all the contents of the question, answers and comments?

Comment: Can you able to see the `deleted recent questions` in this [questions section](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/users/14467/velop?tab=questions)

Comment: Nope, only: `0 Questions: You have not asked any questions` and tabs for views, newest, activity, votes

Comment: Okay, please refer [Why and how are some questions deleted?](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions)

Comment: So basically the question is likely deleted but should be still visible to me for an unlimited amount of time right?

Comment: `Self-deleted posts can be viewed, edited, and undeleted by their original authors.`. Since your question is deleted by moderators, so you can't view the question, until it receives 3 undelete votes

Comment: @Arulkumar authors can also view and edit posts deleted by others (provided they have a link to them).

Comment: It was most likely deleted by Roomba

Comment: It was more than 30 days old, had −1 or lower score and no answers, hence automatically deleted. The only advice I can give is: check your questions more often.

Comment: You should probably ask this at the [meta.cogsci.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question was asked more than 60 days ago, and is currently deleted*, it will not show up in any lists or searches, except to ♦ moderators. However, if you dig through your old comments, you should be able to find its URL, and then you can view the question. Then you can make the appropriate edits, and ask on CogSci's meta (or perhaps in chat?) for someone to vote to undelete it. (I don't recall off-hand if you can vote to undelete your own Roomba'd questions — the most likely cause of deletion — but if so that would save time.)

To find a comment that has a link to the question will probably require a lot of digging through your [network inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox) (your CogSci profile, unfortunately, conceals actions taken on deleted posts most of the time, including revisions and comments). I have just verified that this allows me to find a post of my own that was deleted months ago.

<sub>**The careful phrasing here is deliberate. The date of deletion is irrelevant, but the date of posting is very relevant.*</sub>

Comment: The network inbox revealed the link to the question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

December 2016 is too long ago for your question to be shown in the [Recently deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185491/295232) list, which goes back only 60 days. Your best bet is to ask a Cognitive Science ♦ moderator in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=cogsci.stackexchange.com), or open a question on [the site's own Meta](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/). A ♦ moderator will be able to find the question for you, and with the link you'll be able to edit it into better shape. You can then flag the question for undeletion.