# Shared IP Answer Ban workarounds?

Tags: support, answers, post-ban, ban

I browse from a shared IP address (my university gives no other option) and I, for the first time ever, decided to answer a question on Stack Exchange.

I have apparently been answer banned but I have no deleted answers or even deleted posts.

I have a reputation of 10, not very good but surely not answer ban worthy?

I read on the FAQ question [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997) that this might have something to do with my IP address.

Are there any workarounds other than paying for a VPN?

Answer (score 14):

Your IP has nothing to do with your answer ban. You do have a few deleted answers, but they are from April and August so you [can't see them in your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile/185492#185492) anymore. I recommend looking at editing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657226/jekyll-redirect-link/43585839#43585839) and let me know when you are satisfied with it. In the future, try to provide more details in your answer than just a link.

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm getting back to you on this so late... Could you please take another look at that answer? I would really like to try contributing again.