# Curious badge is not being awarded

Tags: discussion, support, badges

Why have I not received the Curious badge, even though I have asked 11 positive voted questions?

That's what the badge tracker indicates:

[image]

---

These are my question list.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/4431643/kiran-biradar?tab=questions&sort=newest

Comment: Deleted questions also count.

Comment: @AnneDaunted Pardon me. I did not get your pointer.

Comment: If you have deleted questions with negative scores, they influence your *positive question record*. It may look positive in the stats, but in reality isn't.

Comment: Hey, kiran, I've edited your question to try to make to flow a little better.  If you don't like it, feel free to roll it back.  As for the badge, there's more to it than just a set number of well-received questions; see that part about maintaining a positive question record?  That one is harder to hit, and somewhat confusing to understand.

Comment: @fbueckert Thank you for the edit, it is more clearer now.

Comment: I did not understand `maintain a positive question record` part, does it mean profile should not receive any negative votes at all for the questions?

Comment: A good reference for that part is in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/67399#67399), under the `Additional criteria for this badge family` heading.

Comment: TL;DR: you have other questions which are considered "bad", which counter your good questions. The 11 is the amount of days, not of questions.

Comment: Imagine you asked 10 questions, 5 have a +1 score, 5 have a -1 score. You have no positive question record. Now you delete the 5 questions with -1 scores - it seems to be positive now, but it isn't and that's what counts.

Comment: @AnneDaunted This clears my doubt, how to see all the deleted questions so that I can counter act?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/377968).

Comment: @kiranBiradar with less than 10k rep you can't (unless they were recently deleted, for which Anne gave link), only way is asking a moderator to give you a list.

Comment: @kiranBiradar Here's a couple to be going on with. I expect there are more ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561578/getting-warning-for-pthread-cleanup-pushplaylist-cleanup-handler-void-pspli) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667254/mdio-read-time-out-while-play-back-is-happening-from-gstreamer))