# Could we clarify the "votes cast" user feedback?

Tags: discussion, information-display

On the user profile page, under "Impact", you can see the amount of votes you have cast. When you mouse over the number, there is a rollover description.

[image: "Total number of up and down votes cast"]

However, when I click on the number, this takes me to a more in-depth description of these votes. The in-depth feedback suggests that this number does *not* only represent up and down votes; it *also* represents votes to close, delete, undelete or open a question.

[image: "Votes cast" can be filtered under the categories of "all", "upvote", "downvote", "deletion", "undelete", "closure" and "reopen".]

I know that the show tally includes all of these votes, as I only have roughly 1100 votes listed under upvotes and downvotes, and must include delete votes and reopen votes to reach the original number.

---

<del>From this point of view, a rollover description that only mentions up and downvotes is a bit misleading. Could we ammend the "votes cast" rollover description to include *all* votes included in this tally? We could be more generic, and simply mention that it is "the total number of cast votes", or we could be more detailed, and simply include the additional vote types.</del>

> <del>Total number of votes cast.</del>
>
> <del>Total number of votes cast, including upvotes, downvotes, delete votes, undelete votes, close votes and reopen votes.</del>

It has since been pointed out that the confusion comes from a *differant* value I have been looking at; please read below.

---

As it has since been pointed out, this number includes posts that are not otherwise counted, when I explicitly look at a particular type of votes. For example, my user profile shows that I have cast 908 downvotes, but my downvotes page explicitly states that I have only cast 518 downvotes. Perhaps this could be cleared up by stating that the indepth display does not show *all* votes. Something like "908 total votes, 518 shown".

Answer (score 3):

> 1100 votes listed under upvotes and downvotes

No, there are much more including the one's you casted on deleted posts

> only mentions up and downvotes is a bit misleading.

You are mistaken.

The 1458 is the total UP and DOWN votes casted by you excluding close/ reopen etc.

#### I would like to post this image of your activity tab here

[image]

> 908 + 550 = 1458

Comment: Where do you see that information? Im directly counting the votes as they are listed *individually*; I view 30 votes per page, and I have 18 pages of downvotes, and 19 pages of upvotes. Assuming the first page is full, that gives us (30*18 + 30*19) = 30*37=1110.  Under the downvotes tab, it *explicitly* states "518 Votes Cast".

Comment: check your profile -> activity -> summary and at the right bottom.

Comment: I see, now, where you see the "total votes"; but this number contradicts the explicit number when I look at the detailed view (only viewable to the user, themselves). Even if this number does *not* include deleted votes, it lists upvotes as "546"; so I have only upvoted 4 questions that have since been deleted? I have certainly upvoted far more that have since been deleted.

Comment: questions put on hold or closed will count. Only deleted questions are excluded. Also 550 up is the total upvotes you casted on questions + answers.

Comment: This still makes the information provided confusing; the provided information contradicts itself. Maybe it should say something like "908 votes (518 shown)".

Comment: I have updated my question as such. Thanks for clearing this up, though.

Answer (score 1):

The upvotes and downvotes filters of the votes tab are excluding deleted posts, by design, even for users with the Moderator Tools (10k rep on graduated sites) privilege.

This is mentioned in [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140328/dont-hide-undeletion-votes-cast-on-deleted-posts):

> I'm a big fan of the votes tab in the profile page, as it allows me to keep track of my usage of the moderation tools. Or at least it would, if **votes cast on deleted posts didn't unceremoniously disappear**.

Three years ago (July 2014) the request has been fulfilled, and 10k users can since then see deleted posts in the delete, undelete, closure, and reopen filters of the votes tab, however this does not include the upvotes and downvotess filters.

On the other hand, the number in the user profile counts all downvotes ever cast, including on posts there were since then deleted. So, if you see there 908 and in the downvotes tab only 518 posts, it means 390 posts you downvoted have been deleted since the downvote.